# Why does my printer print a blank page after every print job?

Tags: printing, canon

The printer has been doing this for a while, I think since I got it. The blank page doesn't seem to be in the files themselves, no blank page shows in any of the files, it's been doing it with different file types and whether I print with LibreOffice or Firefox. I checked the Printer Options and the options that show before printing but couldn't find an option that seemed related to my issue. Some search results say the problem could be caused by a seperator page but I couldn't find anything about that in the options.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and it's up to date. The printer is Canon MG3600. In Ubuntu settings, for Printer Details it sais that the driver is 'Canon MG3600 Series - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.13'. The printer is connected by cable directly to my computer.

Comment: Install Boomaga virtual printer driver and try to print your file(s) to this virtual printer. Does the extra empty page show up in Boomaga too?

Comment: What is the printer's default papersize? `http://localhost:631/printers`

Comment: @FedonKadifeli I installed it and no it doesn't show up there, only 1 page total. And when I actually print it, the blank page gets printed too.

Comment: @waltinator under defaults it sais media=iso_a4_210x297mm so A4, which is the paper I print on

Comment: And what happens when you print a single page over Boomaga? I mean print a single page from LibreOffice to Boomaga (verify that there is a single page in Boomaga) and then print that page from Boomaga to Canon printer. If it prints an extra blank page; you should check Canon printer settings. Does the Canon printer have a web interface to access its settings? (I mean not the CUPS Linux web interface @waltinator indicated, but the Canon printer's own web interface.)

Comment: @FedonKadifeli Ok now I printed 1 page from LibreOffice to Boomaga, and in Boomaga it was still 1 page. Then I printed from Boomaga to the Canon printer and it prints 1 page + 1 blank page. I found out how to access the Canon printer webinterface (indeed not the CUPS web interface) but there aren't alot of settings there and none seem applicaple to my problem :(

Comment: Is there anything that you see in `system-config-printer`? (Right click on your Canon printer and select **Properties**.) Check that no banners are enabled, for example...

Comment: Check `lpoptions`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying some settings, the problem seems to be in one sided printing, kinda weird because I wouldn't expect that would need to result in an extra blank page. I don't think I had changed that setting before. But I set it to 'Long Edge (Standard)' and now it's fixed. In LibreOffice: File -> Printer Settings... -> Properties... -> Duplex. In Firefox in the print dialog -> Page Setup: Two-sided. It doesn't print a blank page at the end whether printing an even or odd number of pages. Changing it in Ubuntu settings in Printing Options or in `system-config-printer` in Printer Options fixes it for printing test pages. But for printing in LibreOffice or Firefox, the setting there takes precedence, so if for example two-sided is off in Firefox and on everywhere else, you will still have the problem when printing from Firefox.